# how to resize webview when I dynamic hide navigationbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I used `wkWebView` to develop a browser, when I dynamic hide the
 navigationbar of `viewController`, navigationbar of webpage won't resize.  such as the website:code4app.com

[example](http://7lrznz.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/1.png)

Comment: I have resolved this question : wkwebview.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;